# Can you check trial while app is running in background

Tags: windows-phone-8

I followed the [MS article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh286402(v=vs.105).aspx) to implement a trial experience in my phone...

I was wondering if anybody has tried to use this when the application is running in the background and what problems they had?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? it should be very easy to try out in the API in a Background Task and get an answer.

Comment: Haven't tried it yet... I was just wondering if the code would work and wondered if anybody had done this and what their results were ... ( why reinvent the wheel? )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trial app failed for me... closing this question as answered.